# CodeIgniter AJAX Insertion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to create photo tag using codeigniter I am referring this site 
(http://techlister.com/php/simple-photo-tagging-with-php-and-jquery/1176/)
Data insertion is not working properly.It's a great help  if you can help me to solve this issue.

here is my code

### controller

```
public function addImageData()
    {
        $this->load->model('test_model');
        $this->test_model->insert_imageData();

    }
```

### model

```
public function insert_imageData()
{
        $data = array(
            'id' => $this->input->post('pic_id'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'pic_x' => $this->input->post('pic_x'),
            'pic_y' => $this->input->post('pic_y')
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('image_tag', $data);
        return $insert;
}
```

### view -code segment

```
 // Save button click - save tagsfe
        $( document ).on( 'click',  '#tagit #btnsave', function(){
            name = $('#tagname').val();
            var img = $('#imgtag').find( 'img' );
            var id = $( img ).attr( 'id' );
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url().'Treatments_Controller/addImageData'; ?>",
                data: "pic_id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&pic_x=" + mouseX + "&pic_y=" + mouseY + "&type=insert",
                cache: true,
                success: function(data){
                    //viewtag( id );
                    $('#tagit').fadeOut();
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ur url like this

```
       url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Treatments_Controller/addImageData",
```

Comment: Please, provide details of your answer. Only code isn't enough.

Comment: @Sergey Denisov  still it's not working. In site demo when we click on picture it shows a input field to enter text and when we save it data save in database and the text box fade out.here I did all the changes all  provided above but that text box doesn't fade out and data doesn't saved in database.instead if I just entered the url which I gave in ajax function in another tab, null values save in database (means controller and model part working.something wrong with ajax part i don't know) Hope you  got my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
In view page,
if you are having a button:
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="insert()"><button> Insert </button>
<script>
function insert(){
     name = $('#tagname').val();
     var img = $('#imgtag').find( 'img' );
     var id = $( img ).attr( 'id' );
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url();?>+'Treatments_Controller/addImageData'",
                    data: {"pic_id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&pic_x=" + mouseX + "&pic_y=" + mouseY + "&type=insert"},
                    success: function(data){
                        //viewtag( id );
                        $('#tagit').fadeOut();
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

            });
```

you can also do in ajax:

```
           data: $("#form_id").serialize(),
```

also add `echo "inserted";` in controller. for the response